# Convert two arrays into one JSON object using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I have the arrays `name[]` and `lastname[]`. How do I combine and convert them into a JSON string? I want it to be in the following format. I need the "Employees" title in the JSON.

```
{ "Employees" : [
    {"name": "John", "lastname": "Coleman"},
    {"name": "Chip", "lastname": "Dale"},
    {"name": "Ann", "lastname": "Smith"},
    {"name": "Terry", "lastname": "Johnson"},
    {"name": "Mary", "lastname": "Loggins"},
    {"name": "Timothy", "lastname": "Lopez"},
    {"name": "Jessica", "lastname": "Brown"}
]}
```

I need an efficient way to do this as the arrays have a lot of items in them. I actually have more than two arrays that I need to combine into a JSON object. For simplicity I demonstrated what I want with two. They all have the same number of items and are ordered. I do not want to iterate the arrays and construct the JSON string myself.

**Update:**

I forgot to mention that my arrays are  `IEnumerable<[]>` both string and integer arrays. Here is what I tried the arrays are created in another class.

```
  public string[] Name {
                get{ return  (Employees ?? Enumerable.Empty<Employee> ()).Select (p => p.name).ToArray(); }
            }

    public string[] Lastname {
                get{ return  (Employees ?? Enumerable.Empty<Employee> ()).Select (p => p.lastname).ToArray(); }
            }

    public int[] Age {
                get{ return  (Employees ?? Enumerable.Empty<Employee> ()).Select (p => p.age).ToArray(); }
            }
```

I then access them

```
var name = X.Select(s => s.Name).ToArray();
var lastname = X.Select(s => s.Lastname).ToArray();
var age = X.Select(s => s.Age).ToArray();

var employees = new { Employees = Enumerable.Range(0, name.Length).Select(i => new { name = name[i], lastname = lastname[i], age = age[i] }) };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees, Formatting.Indented);
Debug.WriteLine(json);
```

For some reason this returns something similar to

```
{"Employees":[{"name":["John","Chip","Ann","Terry"],"lastname":["Coleman","Dale","Smith","Johnson"],"age":[42, 26, 33, 24]}]}
```

where all the names, lastnames are all put together. How do I get the correct format?

Comment: Please show us your `name` and `lastname` arrays.

Comment: What is `X` in the updated example?  Is it an enumerable over classes that contain a list of employees by some chance?

Comment: Its a different deserialized json object

Comment: Is it an object or an enumerable of objects containing properties `public string[] Name` and `public string[] Lastname` and `public int[] Age`?  If so, you have arrays of arrays of strings, not arrays of strings.  You need to flatten them with, say, `SelectMany`.

Comment: Yes its an enumerable containing properties. If I do public string[] Name {
                get{ return  (Employees ?? Enumerable.Empty<Employee> ()).SelectMany (p => p.name); }
            } I get the error Error CS0411: The type arguments for method `System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine them with [`Zip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) into an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), then serialize that:

```
        string[] name = new string[] { "John", "Chip" };
        string[] lastname = new string[] { "Coleman", "Dale" };

        var employees = new { Employees = name.Zip(lastname, (n1, n2) => new { name = n1, lastname = n2 }) };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees, Formatting.Indented);
        Debug.WriteLine(json);
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> {
>   "Employees": [
>     {
>       "name": "John",
>       "lastname": "Coleman"
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "Chip",
>       "lastname": "Dale"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

For multiple arrays, it might be easier to use [`Enumerable.Range()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to iterate through the arrays in parallel:

```
        string[] name = new string[] { "John", "Chip" };
        string[] lastname = new string[] { "Coleman", "Dale" };
        string[] title = new string[] { "Mr", "Dr" };
        string[] profession = new string[] { "Coder", "Doctor" };

        var employees2 = new { Employees = Enumerable.Range(0, name.Length).Select(i => new { title = title[i], name = name[i], lastname = lastname[i], profession = profession[i] }) };
        var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees2, Formatting.Indented);
        Debug.WriteLine(json2);
```

**Update**

If your strings are in an `IEnumerable<String[]>`, you can convert that outer enumerable to an array then index into it.  For instance, given the following test case:

```
        string[] name = new string[] { "John", "Chip" };
        string[] lastname = new string[] { "Coleman", "Dale" };
        string[] title = new string[] { "Mr", "Dr" };
        string[] profession = new string[] { "Coder", "Doctor" };

        IEnumerable<string[]> strings = new[] { title, name, lastname, profession };
```

You could do:

```
        var stringArray = strings.ToArray();

        var employees2 = new { Employees = Enumerable.Range(0, name.Length).Select(i => new { title = stringArray[0][i], name = stringArray[1][i], lastname = stringArray[2][i], profession = stringArray[3][i] }) };
        var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees2, Formatting.Indented);
        Debug.WriteLine(json2);
```

Which results in:

> ```
> {
>   "Employees": [
>     {
>       "title": "Mr",
>       "name": "John",
>       "lastname": "Coleman",
>       "profession": "Coder"
>     },
>     {
>       "title": "Dr",
>       "name": "Chip",
>       "lastname": "Dale",
>       "profession": "Doctor"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

**Update 2**

If you actually have an enumeration of objects containing enumeration of employees, you can flatten them with [Enumerable.SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  For instance, given the following classes:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string someMoreDataThatShouldNotBeSerialized { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeContainer
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

You could flatten them as follows:

```
        var X = GetAllEmployees();

        var employees = X.SelectMany(s => s.Employees ?? Enumerable.Empty<Employee>()).Select(e => new { name = e.name, lastname = e.lastname, age = e.age });
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees, Formatting.Indented);
        Debug.WriteLine(json);
```

Then the test setup

```
    public static IEnumerable<EmployeeContainer> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        return new[] { 
            new EmployeeContainer { 
                Employees = 
                    new[] { 
                        new Employee { name = "John", lastname = "Coleman", age = 42, someMoreDataThatShouldNotBeSerialized = "someMoreData1" },
                        new Employee { name = "Chip", lastname = "Dale", age = 26, someMoreDataThatShouldNotBeSerialized = "someMoreData2" },
                    } 
            },
            new EmployeeContainer { 
                Employees = 
                    new[] { 
                        new Employee { name = "Ann", lastname = "Smith", age = 33, someMoreDataThatShouldNotBeSerialized = "someMoreData3" },
                        new Employee { name = "Terry", lastname = "Johnson", age = 24, someMoreDataThatShouldNotBeSerialized = "someMoreData4" }, 
                    } 
            },
            new EmployeeContainer()
        };
    }
```

Produces:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "name": "John",
>     "lastname": "Coleman",
>     "age": 42
>   },
>   {
>     "name": "Chip",
>     "lastname": "Dale",
>     "age": 26
>   },
>   {
>     "name": "Ann",
>     "lastname": "Smith",
>     "age": 33
>   },
>   {
>     "name": "Terry",
>     "lastname": "Johnson",
>     "age": 24
>   }
> ]
> ```

Working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bam33Y).

Comment: Would this work with more than 2 arrays? Zip() only takes 2 arrays as params. Would you just run multiple Zips after each other for say 7+ arrays? Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling - Well, since they're arrays, you could do `Enumerable.Range(0, array0.Length).Select(i => new { a = array0[i], b = array1[i], c = array2[i], ... })`   Otherwise it's multiple zips, or create your own extension method with multiple inputs.

Comment: Right, the first one was obvious, but the author asked not to iterate over arrays, however Zip() does that anyways (but you don't have to write code for it). I don't know exactly what he/she is trying to attempt. Good to know you can string multiple Zips! (Although an extension method is way nicer)

Comment: I think this answer is awesome and I learned a lot from it, thank you.

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling - I interpreted that to mean that OP didn't want to write a manual `foreach` loop.  At some level of code (maybe Json.NET itself) one needs to visit each array element.

Comment: @dbc Agreed! The edit to your answer makes it a great answer by the way.

Comment: My arrays are actually IEnumerable<String[]> so it doesn't have a Length method. I replaced it with Count. But then Im getting the errors: Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(int, int)' has some invalid arguments and Error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert `method group' expression to type `int'. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: @Carell - I suggest that you evaluate the outer enumerable by `var arrays = arrayEnumerable.ToArray()`.  Presumably there aren't that many different arrays, then after you've done that you can index into them.  Otherwise, update your question with more details and I can take a look.

Comment: Fixed the error. But the output JSON is not in the correct format. It is putting all of the names, last names together as follows. {"Employees":[{"name":["John","Chip","Ann","Terry"],"last name":["Coleman","Dale","Smith","Johnson"]}]}

Comment: @Carell - could you update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of you problem?

Comment: Sure, let me see what I can do.

Comment: @dbc updated question with details. Your code returns the correct format for your example but not for my case.

Comment: You answered my question but I still can't seem to replicate your solution with a JSON url. I have been stuck for days. I actually get my arrays from another JSON url. I provided an example JSON url. Can you take a look my update and maybe change the fiddle by using the url?